# Mongo db replication using node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, replication, ssh-tunnel

I am new to MongoDB and NodeJS. I am running an ec2 instance on AWS and I want to sync the data of AWS to local systems and local to AWS. I don't have any idea about how to do it. I have tried some configuration in database files but I am not able to connect my local system with remote server.

I found this repository on git hub https://github.com/sheharyarn/mongo-sync but I don't know how to use that repository in my code.

Kindly help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Mongodb atlas provides free 512MB of space. You can create cluster in mongoldb atlas and use online database from anywhere. it will work on your local machine and also on aws server.

Just open mongoldb website you can find mongoldb atlas easily. after sign up.

Comment: Is there is any other way to do in mongo db?

Comment: yes there are other ways too but it will take some more manual configuration every time. you have to export and import database after every change. so it is better to have database online.